# A connection on $Hom( E,E)$ whose parallel transport is compatible to parallel transport of $E$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

According to the  answer of  Sebastan  and previous  edit of  Ben  McKay I revise my post as follows:

Assume that $E$ is a vector bundle over a manifold  $M$  with a connection $\nabla$.
Is there a (unique) connection
$\nabla'$ on $E':=Hom (E,E)$ with the following property;

For every curve $\gamma$ which connects point $x$ to $y$, with $\nabla$ parallel transport $\phi$ and $\nabla'$ parallel transport $\psi$, we have
$\psi(T)=\phi T\phi^{-1}$.
Moreover if $\nabla$ is a Riemannian connection corresponding to a Riemannian metric on $E$, can we choose a Riemannian comnnection $\nabla '$ as above.In the latter we consider the natural Riemannian metric inducing by initial metric on $E$ defined by $tr(AB^{*})$ on the $E'$- bundle

Comment: @Ben  thank you for your edit. It seems that we were editing simultanously. In my new edit I fix  my errors you pointed out.

Comment: Perhaps it should be pointed out that this is a special case of a more general fact:  Each connection $\nabla$ on $E$ induces a canonical connection $\nabla^{r,s}$ on $E^{\otimes r}\otimes (E^*)^{\otimes s}$ that is compatible with all tensor products, contractions, sub-representations, etc., so all of the parallel transports are also compatible.  Your case is just $(r,s)=(1,1)$.

Comment: @RobertBryant  Thank you very much for  your  comment. And the Riemannian property would  be  preserved?

Comment: Yes, certainly.

Answer (score 2):

No, because your formula does not make sense:

$T\in Hom(E_x,X_x)$ and $\phi\in Hom(E_x,E_y)$ invertible means that
$$\phi^{-1}\circ T\circ \phi$$ is not well-defined unless $x=y.$

If you define $$\psi=\phi\circ T\circ \phi^{-1},$$ then $\psi$ is actually the parallel-transport of the induced connection $\nabla^{End}$ on the endomorphism bundle which is defined by satisfying the equation
$$(\nabla^{End}T)(e)=\nabla T(e)-T(\nabla e)$$
for all  $T\in\Gamma(Hom(E,E))$ and sections $e\in\Gamma(E).$

For a proof of this property consider $v,w\in E_x$ with $T(v)=w,$ and denote the corresponding parallel sections (along the given curve $\gamma$ from $x$ to $y$) by $v(t)$ and $w(t).$ Then, $\nabla_{\gamma'} v(t)=0$ and $\nabla_{\gamma'}w(t)=0.$ Hence, by uniqueness of solutions of ODE's, the parallel endomorphism field $T(t)$ along $\gamma$ satisfies 
$$T(t)(v(t))=w(t).$$
As $v\in E_x$ is arbitrary, this is equivalent to the equation $\psi=\phi\circ T\circ \phi^{-1}.$

The construction is compatible with metrics, as the same standard arguments for tensor products, dual bundles and corresponding connections carry over to the Riemannian/hermitian situation, i.e., the induced metric on the endomorphism bundle is parallel with respect to $\nabla^{End}.$ 
Note also that $\nabla^{End}$ is the unique connection whose parallel transport satisfies the equation $\psi=\phi\circ T\circ \phi^{-1}.$

Comment: thank you for your answer.I ,ll fix the typos in my post as you pointed out.

Comment: May ellaborate why this connection work or please give a reference.moreover what about the Riemannian part of my question?Does your connection automatically work?